# What are the best practices to use AngularJS with Django

Tags: django, rest, angularjs

I am about to start a project with **AngularJS** for the client side and **Django** for the server side.

What are the best practices to make them work like best friends (static files,auth, deployment, etc.)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are ways of powering your client-side templates from Django templates for interesting optimizations; however, given the similarities between Django and AngularJS's template languages, it's almost never worth the effort here. I will pair static serving of AngularJS with the [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) for most projects of this sort.

My `urls.py` order of operations is almost always the Django REST Framework URLs first (written as strictly as possible), followed by a generic pattern that points everything else to my base AngularJS application template in my `STATIC_ROOT` dir for local testing/dev scenarios:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'', 'serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 
            'path': '/base.html'}
        ),
    )
```

By pointing all of the unmatched requests to the same app/template, you can start using the history-hack method of URLs and routing if you'd prefer that to hashtags. If you plan only to stick to hashtags, your final URL match could be stricter (for example matching `/` (URL root) with `r'^$'`).

In production, I'll use a reverse proxy or slow-clients HTTP server like nginx to serve the AngularJS (static) content, proxying the requests for REST services to the Django WSGI app.

For communicating with the Django REST Framework, I prefer to have class-like JS objects to marshal the data to and from the AngularJS app and the Django REST Framework. For this, I use [angular-django-rest-resource](https://github.com/blacklocus/angular-django-rest-resource) to generate classes that represent the Django model classes I'm exposing in the REST Framework views.

For maximum flexibility in the queries angular-django-rest-resource can make for resources, I will have the *django-filter* backend installed for the REST Framework as described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend). This allows the JS resources to request the Django objects constrained by parameters (e.g. `/polls/?author=345&finished=1`).

If you're deploying the Django and REST operations on a separate domain of servers from whence the AngularJS main template is served (for example, if you're using a third-party CDN on a different Internet domain for the HTML), then it's important to allow cross-domain requests to those resources. For this, I recommend the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) middleware.

I hope this is helpful. It's not *the* best practice set, but it's one that has worked for me.

Comment: How did you manage registration and authentication?

Comment: I plan to use Django for the authentication part.

Comment: Good question. I left it out because every case is different. A "Best Practice" the community has adopted is creating an AngularJS service, which gives you a singleton to query for the user's auth status. [This article](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app) details how one might construct such a service. In the case of using Django's built-in auth, I'd recommend starting by enabling [Django REST Framework's session-based auth](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#sessionauthentication).

Comment: With session authentication exposing `request.user` to the Django REST Framework, you can conditionally expose the requested data. One approach, which I've not yet tried, is to send down the auth information with every serialized JSON response as detailed in [this article](http://glue-talk.com/1509/angular-js-authentication-for-webapplication-and-webservice/). Given you're using Django, you can also create custom views outside of the Django REST Framework that might better convey user or session information to your AngularJS application.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I just now found *angular-django-rest-resource*. Thanks @JustinTurnerArthur!

Comment: @JustinTurnerArthur how do you serve other static angular assets during development please? I can serve `app/index.html` but how do I serve `app/scripts/app.js` for example? Using the above I get back `app/index.html` for *all* non-api endpoints, not just the client-side routing ones

Comment: here is a video that displays the step by step process. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZ8NIoLN-yQ

Answer (score 7):

To prevent mix up of Angularjs with Django refer: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Basically to enable Django to use  {{ xyz }} variables and angular to use {[{ xyz }]} variables together:

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!, I had a problem using django + angular when using {{  }}. It was driving me crazy!!!