# Deploy django with apache2

Tags: python, django, apache

(I am in way over my head) I am trying to deploy my django server on apache2. I have already buildt a quite large front-end application (that is currently deployed with apache2) and do not want to serve any views through django, rather I want to follow the backend as service principal.

I have followed the instructions here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi

After the modwsgi part I get this in my apache log file:

```
  [Tue May 20 12:19:44 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u8 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

After appending this to the apache config file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/PhotodiceServer

<Directory /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This is the content of the wsgi file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PhotodiceServer.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is the content of the urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browseable API.
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
)
# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
model = User

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
model = Group


# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)
```

This is the installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'photod',
)
```

previously when i entered the ip of the webserver (a raspberry pi) i was automagically routed to index.html that is stored in var/www/.

Now when i enter the ip of the webserve i get 404 page not found, do i have to explicetly say what url will load a static file somehow? and how will this play with the routing in angular? (I have used the angular-ui-router.js)?

(if i set debug =False i get Bad Request (400) instead)

Comment: a few questions: why did you use an outdated guide (there's a red warning on a top of that page, try to use an actual guide insted: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ ). Another one is: why Apache? There are much better alternatives such as Nginx (better performance, security etc.)
Also it might be very helpful to post your actual configuration, not just a link to the guide you followed. That means: your Apache .conf file, how/where you installed that Django application.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the post after changing to the other guide. Why apache? lets just say my name is John Snow (i know nothing). I have installed the django application in my var/www directive... using the starproject command i think... i have tried to configure this for a while dont remember exactly

Comment: `Internal Server Error` means there's some error in your app's configuration. Could you put here the content of your `wsgi.py`? Also try to put `DEBUG=True` in the app's settings, so any request will dsiplay an error traceback instead of that laconic error message. Also you can try to run `manage.py runserver` on that server (can you, rights?) and display that page in some console-based browser on that server (links) or store it in an html file wget (`wget http://localhost:8000`)

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is use django as your REST backend for angular. Have a read through [this tutorial](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html) which shows you exactly how to do that. The [what are the best practices to use AngularJS with django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148909/what-are-the-best-practices-to-use-angularjs-with-django) question is also useful; and finally [`django-angular`](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html) was just released as well.

Comment: I removed the [tag:angularjs] tag because this question isn't about angular but rather setting up django with mod_wsgi. It just so happens you are using angular as a front end to your django app, but it has no bearing on this; you have also asked multiple questions in one post. Please keep posts restricted to one (answerable) question.

Comment: I was stupid and read the guide wrong, so the internal erver error is not a problem anymore

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The "Getting Started with Django Rest Framework and AngularJS" is really confusing to me... do I really need bower and grunt? do i have to use virtual environment? will it "serve" using apache instead of doing the manage.py runserver?

Comment: bower and grunt? Not really; virtual environment - absolutely.

Comment: https://learnbatta.com/blog/deploy-django-app-with-apache-server-on-ubuntu-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a couple of things in your Apache config:

1. `AddHandler wsgi-script .py`
2. In `<Directory xxx>`
   `Options +ExecCGI`
   `SetHandler wsgi-script`

Try these, and see what it says then.

EDIT*** as your clearly not familiar with apache!!

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

AddHandler wsgi-script .py
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/PhotodiceServer

<Directory /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer>
    Options +ExecCGI
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Another EDIT***

Here is the config I used,  (although in the end I just ran uWSGI server and ProxyPass to it as it was a bit of a pain!!)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.local.domain

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

    Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/project/favicon.ico

    AliasMatch ^/static/(.*)$ /path/to/project/static/$1

    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/project/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess _WSGI user=chazmead group=www-data processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/path/to/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/path/to/project
    WSGIProcessGroup _WSGI

    <Directory "/path/to/project/project/">
        SetHandler wsgi-script
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what do you mean with 2.?  <Directory Options +ExecCGI SetHandler wsgi-script>
or
 <Directory xxxx >
Options +ExecCGI SetHandler wsgi-script
....
</Directory>

Comment: LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PhotodiceServer/PhotodiceServer/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/PhotodiceServer
AddHandler wsgi-script .py
<Directory /var/www/PhotodiceServer>
Options +ExecCGI
SetHandler wsgi-script
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

Still 404

Comment: @BAYELK See recent edit! don't forget to mark as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, however it did not solve anything:/ Still 404

Comment: does the apache server have execute permissions on the wsgi.py file?  check the group should be www-data (for debian) and permission should be 755 (rwxr-xr-x) for all .py files under PhotodiceServer (root-dir)

Comment: if you are getting a 404.. is this from Django? as this may be a routes problem / no application set up.

Comment: yes the server has persmission. I dont know:/ it says so in the django debug in the browser

Comment: right, so its getting to django... so its an app issue, not an apache issue now!

Comment: try adding an empty url handler: `url(r"^$", "app.views.view")`

Comment: OOh thats nice! no i got "ViewDoesNotExist at /" error instead:)