# What is the best practice method of using Angular JS routing with a Django backend?

Tags: django, angularjs, url, django-urls, angular-routing

I have created a REST API in Django to pull data from my database. I have a front end application built with Angular that makes calls to that same API. The API has a few URL's, and I have one other URL to serve up index.html and handle the routing. Angular injects the "#/" into the URL. Ideally I would not have that, but when I use the HTML5 mode and location provider, Django picks up the URL and does not see the specified URL in its list and therefore throws an error.

I have seen some resources online, but they are not very clear to me.

Basically, what are accepted best practices with regard to creating angular applications with a Django backend.

I appreciate your help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148909/what-are-the-best-practices-to-use-angularjs-with-django

Comment: there isn't a best practice, you simply have to set it up to properly serve index.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to serve the index.html for every url and then do the routing in angular you can do somethings like this in your `<project_folder>.urls.py`

```
from <your_app> import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^.*$', views.index),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the  .* mean before the $?

Comment: It literally means every thing. every URL will match this regex. So for every URL you request your index.html will be sent..

Comment: Be careful with regards to appending slashes. If you use the above regex, it will catch *all* urls including those missing a slash, even if `APPEND_SLASH` is set to `True` in your settings file. 


You can manually set your other routes to include an optional slash with `?$`. For example: `(r'^log/?$', log_viewer)`